# Running command in GCP Composer

Tags: airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

I couldn't run a gcloud command in GCP Composer.
Here is an issue:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) The subcommand "variables" is not supported for Composer environments with Airflow version 2.1.2.
```

Here is the command:

```
gcloud composer environments run composer \
  --location europe-west1 \
  --project=platform-name \
  --impersonate-service-account=SA-account.com variables -- \
  --import /home/airflow/gcs/data/env_var.json
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Before we shoot for an answer response, lets see ... if I look here:

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes

We see that the release just became GA a few days ago.  Could it be that the gcloud command you are running is back-level?  Instead of running "gcloud composer" try "gcloud beta composer" and see if that makes a difference?  If that works, lets see if we can't look a GCP SDK upgrade that gives us a later gcloud command.

Comment: you're right! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for the mentioned release of Composer has only just become available in the last few days before your post.  It is likely that your gcloud version is out of date compared to the product.  Try refreshing the gcloud command by refreshing the GCP SDK.  Alternatively, try the "gcloud beta" commands of gcloud to engage pre-GA function.

The issue you are encountering is likely caused by the gcloud command thinking that the version of Composer being used is not GA and requiring that you use gcloud beta.